# matlab2tikz image not compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

So, I've used [matlab2tikz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) twice, and both times the image didn't compile at first. The first time, I somehow managed to get going, but it was a long time ago, and now I don't remember exactly what was the issue. I keep getting a lot of `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{axis}` in the error log file.

This is the code outputed by the matlab2tikz as is, no change at all:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.396in,
    height=3.357in,
    at={(0.883in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    separate axis lines,
    every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
    xmode=log,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=10000000,
    xminorticks=true,
    every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
    ymin=-100,
    ymax=50,
    ylabel={Magnitude (dB)},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.178,0.153)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-16   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-11   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-07   40.6303410289213\\
    0.0008  40.6303410271841\\
    0.08    40.6303236571791\\
    0.8 40.6286041985749\\
    0.933348740053014   40.6279771024797\\
    1.08892483819819    40.6271236723191\\
    1.27043328218089    40.6259622901261\\
    1.48219662905618    40.6243819666433\\
    1.72925794530051    40.622231823442\\
    2.01750090559112    40.6193068525886\\
    2.35378991036161    40.6153286738188\\
    2.74613355898188    40.6099196008906\\
    3.2038753716163 40.6025678177622\\
    3.73791630173119    40.5925808505799\\
    4.36097433830553    40.5790238298692\\
    5.08788738007624    40.5606383528071\\
    5.93596659465724    40.535737270644\\
    6.92540867765014    40.5020708249415\\
    8.07977682954621    40.4566609321276\\
    9.42656190470811    40.3956042130434\\
    10.9978370959888    40.3138522650729\\
    12.8310217460618    40.2049917354979\\
    14.9697724753495    40.061068581289\\
    17.4650228484347    39.8725295631713\\
    20.3761963382295    39.6283823583299\\
    23.7726214741992    39.3166861819395\\
    27.7351828758763    38.9254499027432\\
    32.3582474904239    38.4439096574556\\
    37.7519119068884    37.863990631353\\
    44.0446242661083    37.1815961525404\\
    51.3862432061008    36.3973240615444\\
    59.9516066905898    35.5163595742427\\
    69.9446957110198    34.5475833306834\\
    81.6034920190898    33.5022003621019\\
    95.2056455749295    32.392296053133\\
    111.075086679118    31.2296421525792\\
    129.589740254042    30.0249031577852\\
    151.190525987385    28.787237833539\\
    176.391858672848    27.5242042902937\\
    205.793898809889    26.2418562899194\\
    240.09684520601 24.9449356862064\\
    280.117609954666    23.6370955071243\\
    326.809272897311    22.3211154943336\\
    381.283778870433    20.9990917422527\\
    444.838418264214    19.6725944126752\\
    518.986721517599    18.3427941949027\\
    605.49450329087 17.0105612411208\\
    706.421914694448    15.6765412810901\\
    824.172505032377    14.3412135288723\\
    961.55046144788 13.0049344413557\\
    1121.82738961222    11.6679707008536\\
    1308.8202258144 10.3305241322794\\
    1526.98213589972    8.99275069671033\\
    1781.50856578183    7.65477524721116\\
    2078.46096908265    6.31670338733143\\
    2424.91115842832    4.9786315274517\\
    2829.10971807447    3.64065607795251\\
    3300.68248854567    2.3028826423835\\
    3850.85980249894    0.965436073809263\\
    4492.74393097897    -0.371527666692865\\
    5241.62110920007    -1.70780675420948\\
    6115.32557263395    -3.04313450642725\\
    7134.66427278985    -4.37715446645798\\
    8323.91238713707    -5.70938742023981\\
    9711.39142355757    -7.03918763801236\\
    11330.1436866739    -8.36568496758986\\
    13218.7191682208    -9.68770871967079\\
    15422.0936009669    -11.0036887324615\\
    17992.7395393026    -12.3115289115435\\
    20991.8759738877    -13.6084495152566\\
    24490.9262394715    -14.8907975156308\\
    28573.2189354276    -16.1538310588762\\
    33335.9723658003    -17.3914963831224\\
    38892.6097575773    -18.5962353779163\\
    45375.4603932603    -19.7588892784702\\
    52938.9109842187    -20.8687935874391\\
    61763.082333624 -21.9141765560205\\
    72058.1188473482    -22.8829527995799\\
    84069.1930459535    -23.7639172868816\\
    98082.3442583926    -24.5481893778775\\
    114431.290543771    -25.2305838566901\\
    133505.376064586    -25.8105028827927\\
    155758.843175232    -26.2920431280804\\
    181721.650037147    -26.6832794072767\\
    212012.091378157    -26.994975583667\\
    247351.52295476 -27.2391227885085\\
    288581.540375024    -27.4276618066262\\
    336684.021389482    -27.5715849608351\\
    392804.50894982 -27.6804454904101\\
    458279.491894321    -27.7621974383806\\
    534668.232939626    -27.8232541574647\\
    623789.901950712    -27.8686640502786\\
    727766.898804363    -27.9023304959812\\
    849075.397564178    -27.9272315781443\\
    990604.315658172    -27.9456170552063\\
    1155724.11238829    -27.9591740759171\\
    1348367.05518312    -27.9691610430993\\
    1573120.8651052 -27.9765128262278\\
    1835337.97174631    -27.981921899156\\
    2141262.97937609    -27.9859000779257\\
    2498181.37990354    -27.9888250487792\\
    2914593.05419609    -27.9909751919805\\
    3400414.69362647    -27.9925555154633\\
    3967215.96244253    -27.9937168976562\\
    4628495.02507993    -27.9945703278169\\
    5400000 -27.9951974239121\\
    54000000    -27.9969168825163\\
    5400000000.00001    -27.9969342525213\\
    5400000000000.01    -27.9969342542584\\
    5.40000000000001e+16    -27.9969342542584\\
    1e+20   -27.9969342542584\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Compensador}

    \addplot [color=mycolor2, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-16   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-11   40.6303410289213\\
    8e-07   40.6303410289213\\
    0.0008  40.6303410271841\\
    0.08    40.630323657178\\
    0.8 40.6286041984559\\
    0.933658053253552   40.627975535667\\
    1.08964670050651    40.6271194066123\\
    1.27169677141134    40.6259535802842\\
    1.48416241490592    40.6243661600328\\
    1.73212523876644    40.6222049339348\\
    2.02151584802252    40.6192629468636\\
    2.35925568910738    40.6152589919656\\
    2.75342259227421    40.609811303014\\
    3.21344397160885    40.6024022080677\\
    3.7503223034646 40.592330878324\\
    4.37689827615767    40.57865060187\\
    5.10815790475775    40.5600863173635\\
    5.96159095633482    40.5349276569853\\
    6.95760925823194    40.5008928684394\\
    8.12003489417465    40.454960429842\\
    9.47666996455751    40.3931691206156\\
    11.059961538044 40.3103954984242\\
    12.9077776983366    40.2001322593726\\
    15.0643132470732    40.0543134237562\\
    17.5811467248301    39.8632615978651\\
    20.5184740313374    39.6158610876397\\
    23.94654814979  39.3000700650454\\
    27.9473594095942    38.9038469141758\\
    32.6165964749238    38.4164558373171\\
    38.0659349606675    37.8299449400086\\
    44.4257084133164    37.1404288812431\\
    51.8480255394837    36.3487730524861\\
    60.5104082377934    35.4604379445536\\
    70.6200374460949    34.484540086146\\
    82.4187083532673    33.4324508781597\\
    96.1886134909797    32.3163449339361\\
    112.259092021433    31.1480163961872\\
    131.014506645928    29.9381044333509\\
    152.903436528765    28.6957145973466\\
    178.44940610653 27.4283398972736\\
    208.263406387095    26.1419679219374\\
    243.05850821416 24.8412794796751\\
    283.666917007431    23.529874511002\\
    331.059876881994    22.2104883239885\\
    386.370900200003    20.8851807426378\\
    450.922878143197    19.5554927734379\\
    526.259720718332    18.2225718327956\\
    614.183282939544    16.8872694607842\\
    716.796460362763    15.5502163099272\\
    836.553484701668    14.2118790413503\\
    976.318622461292    12.8726031713126\\
    1139.434680503  11.5326452033955\\
    1329.80295701001    10.1921967073313\\
    1551.97655006598    8.85140242651633\\
    1811.26925553721    7.51037402865541\\
    2113.8826588036 6.16920075268818\\
    2467.05446003127    4.82795793730473\\
    2879.2315805291 3.48671422792502\\
    3360.27219042869    2.14553813759458\\
    3612.10258138367    1.51823510432511\\
    3921.68148964712    0.804504572866084\\
    4576.88688138052    -0.536298079899967\\
    5341.55911953932    -1.87675968848373\\
    6233.9871111098 -3.21673826237596\\
    7275.51533770813    -4.55604729286026\\
    8491.05435827617    -5.89443990669691\\
    9909.67660277276    -7.23158953932801\\
    11565.3117066464    -8.56706784588539\\
    13497.5580166224    -9.90032297452577\\
    15752.6296768457    -11.2306663222081\\
    18384.4619471348    -12.5572850195572\\
    21456.0011895949    -13.8793116137544\\
    25040.7103766038    -15.1959996099325\\
    29224.3261278824    -16.5070641194862\\
    34106.909300257 -17.8132297239796\\
    39805.2381747168    -19.1169525316136\\
    46455.601479375 -20.42312987975\\
    54217.0580499451    -21.7394124499387\\
    63275.2410900582    -23.0756306225556\\
    73846.798019116 -24.4420735319621\\
    86184.5720969201    -25.8470303414196\\
    100583.649755626    -27.2947718913273\\
    117388.418274969    -28.7852538490341\\
    137000.802601401    -30.3158862079326\\
    159889.878313748    -31.8844343701394\\
    186603.090651701    -33.491590528236\\
    217779.347936204    -35.1422315180356\\
    254164.30254118 -36.8451985260768\\
    296628.184896432    -38.6119547390059\\
    346186.61706317 -40.4546075672964\\
    404024.903687041    -42.383751871573\\
    471526.381302995    -44.4065701172704\\
    550305.504031308    -46.5255971956538\\
    642246.456985732    -48.7384200303836\\
    749548.220922861    -51.0383128166543\\
    874777.165958129    -53.4155234172601\\
    1020928.4322489 -55.8587795902706\\
    1191497.56570589    -58.3566307044044\\
    1390564.12206664    -60.8984096746682\\
    1622889.23891621    -63.4747764664504\\
    1894029.50931581    -66.0779171541315\\
    2210469.88059072    -68.7015118674886\\
    2579778.75685993    -71.3405760671341\\
    3010789.01494339    -73.9912512130694\\
    3513809.26306152    -76.6505915487854\\
    4100870.39506791    -79.3163711525459\\
    4786013.33713027    -81.9869207570676\\
    5585624.86898824    -84.6609955360804\\
    6518829.55173024    -87.3376710079947\\
    7607947.1359502 -90.0162626825295\\
    8879026.39025901    -92.6962648925917\\
    10362468.1178951    -95.3773046907688\\
    12093752.26232  -98.0591073475592\\
    14114286.4922105    -100.741470664868\\
    16472396.5617252    -103.424245924098\\
    19224482.1328011    -106.107323793766\\
    22436365.7036484    -108.790623926395\\
    224363657.036484    -148.788943769074\\
    22436365703.6484    -228.788926796022\\
    22436365703648.4    -348.788926794325\\
    2.24363657036484e+17    -508.788926794325\\
    1e+20   -614.750826385572\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Loop de Corrente em Malha Aberta}

    \addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   1.54292394648526e-14\\
    6.66666666666759e-13    1.54292394648526e-14\\
    6.66666666666759e-08    1.54292394648526e-14\\
    0.000666666666666758    1.3500584531746e-14\\
    0.666666666666759   -8.26708293805402e-11\\
    66.6666666666759    -8.26870011337924e-07\\
    666.666666666759    -8.26864051082017e-05\\
    778.890771786889    -0.000112867420555789\\
    910.006251562037    -0.000154064535941829\\
    1063.19320741493    -0.000210298517218128\\
    1242.16706682281    -0.000287057571002689\\
    1451.26869804862    -0.000391832834011076\\
    1695.56969443962    -0.000534849219037435\\
    1980.99538188053    -0.000730062865054596\\
    2314.46853284847    -0.000996522438065902\\
    2704.07727273984    -0.00136022707769961\\
    3159.27125090315    -0.00185666252023427\\
    3691.09083434961    -0.0025342640882715\\
    4312.43488305253    -0.00345914868513465\\
    5038.37360151153    -0.00472159019481194\\
    5886.51405454719    -0.00644490524305459\\
    6877.42721261999    -0.00879770872706377\\
    8035.14688431749    -0.0120109680452925\\
    9387.75263721931    -0.0164020856230169\\
    10968.0508454207    -0.022409674821438\\
    12814.3703819796    -0.0306453313338698\\
    14971.4922551726    -0.0419734862598124\\
    17491.7357361468    -0.0576386196036108\\
    20436.2273211267    -0.0794715716557583\\
    23876.3833058438    -0.110221676794693\\
    27895.6419308485    -0.154070365696059\\
    32591.4871095095    -0.217364278615351\\
    38077.8128226072    -0.309529309282892\\
    44487.6855260296    -0.44396210134712\\
    51976.5715715652    -0.63845860167214\\
    60726.1079193109    -0.9145567271784\\
    70948.5075973192    -1.29530106922591\\
    82891.7067593944    -1.80160791283656\\
    96845.3781788223    -2.44842038436318\\
    113147.957030528    -3.24240025243998\\
    132194.849366409    -4.18227950222334\\
    154448.022373859    -5.26153293861644\\
    180447.209021576    -6.47193453834754\\
    210822.998852379    -7.80653534878038\\
    213109.73159745 -7.9035610664232\\
    246312.1324298  -9.26128327747976\\
    287775.370393042    -10.835190417512\\
    336218.370519995    -12.5293360931429\\
    392816.079154819    -14.3451584983039\\
    458941.228594731    -16.2825747032065\\
    536197.631617386    -18.3384872354153\\
    626459.080681065    -20.5061069739647\\
    731914.795266769    -22.775227454851\\
    855122.519651245    -25.1332442683552\\
    999070.558955123    -27.5665022462189\\
    1167250.25810101    -30.0615568686588\\
    1363740.68160092    -32.6060943686751\\
    1593307.54801376    -35.1894426645877\\
    1861518.81864921    -37.802734279119\\
    2174879.74402996    -40.4388332727386\\
    2540990.6435564 -43.092134131087\\
    2968731.24519395    -45.7583125526517\\
    3468476.05619497    -48.4340773664478\\
    4052345.9885005 -51.1169487082971\\
    4734502.34179533    -53.8050718508377\\
    5531490.27454094    -56.4970672009555\\
    6462640.0936024 -59.1919127199115\\
    7550536.09542924    -61.8888535018907\\
    8821564.33015925    -64.5873331695161\\
    10306552.5742267    -67.2869423212165\\
    12041518.0335007    -69.9873800596794\\
    14068540.9118968    -72.6884254256942\\
    16436785.0331718    -75.3899162640424\\
    19203690.2702709    -78.091733629183\\
    22436365.7036484    -80.7937903008019\\
    224363657.036484    -120.792010521114\\
    22436365703.6484    -200.791992541865\\
    22436365703648.4    -320.791992540067\\
    2.24363657036484e+17    -480.791992540067\\
    1e+20   -586.753892131313\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Função de Transferência do Sistema Original}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.396in,
    height=1.519in,
    at={(0.883in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    separate axis lines,
    every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
    xmode=log,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=10000000,
    xminorticks=true,
    every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
    ymin=-90.9,
    ymax=0.9,
    ytick={-90, -45,   0},
    ylabel={Phase (deg)},
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   0\\
    8e-16   0\\
    8e-11   -1.1455085740759e-10\\
    8e-07   -1.14549117008068e-06\\
    0.0008  -0.00114549117692524\\
    0.08    -0.11454896491963\\
    0.8 -1.14533842499353\\
    0.933348740053014   -1.33618587793538\\
    1.08892483819819    -1.55880710027685\\
    1.27043328218089    -1.818476119719\\
    1.48219662905618    -2.12133303644379\\
    1.72925794530051    -2.47452075345443\\
    2.01750090559112    -2.88634004788448\\
    2.35378991036161    -3.36642346719528\\
    2.74613355898188    -3.92592715171453\\
    3.2038753716163 -4.57773726880743\\
    3.73791630173119    -5.3366837138457\\
    4.36097433830553    -6.21974724324063\\
    5.08788738007624    -7.24623607584126\\
    5.93596659465724    -8.43789270013323\\
    6.92540867765014    -9.81886941436745\\
    8.07977682954621    -11.4154805766546\\
    9.42656190470811    -13.2556008465206\\
    10.9978370959888    -15.3675363667826\\
    12.8310217460618    -17.7781633316975\\
    14.9697724753495    -20.5101344187963\\
    17.4650228484347    -23.578046695301\\
    20.3761963382295    -26.9837068111988\\
    23.7726214741992    -30.7110619074574\\
    27.7351828758763    -34.721934720561\\
    32.3582474904239    -38.9541749354155\\
    37.7519119068884    -43.3238058482039\\
    44.0446242661083    -47.7318514170611\\
    51.3862432061008    -52.0748902631241\\
    59.9516066905898    -56.2567865361712\\
    69.9446957110198    -60.1985005680472\\
    81.6034920190898    -63.8437644168725\\
    95.2056455749295    -67.1601143625849\\
    111.075086679118    -70.1362745521386\\
    129.589740254042    -72.7775505278354\\
    151.190525987385    -75.1007560490389\\
    176.391858672848    -77.1296655616337\\
    205.793898809889    -78.8914351984178\\
    240.09684520601 -80.4140504017032\\
    280.117609954666    -81.7246588621775\\
    326.809272897311    -82.8485816267825\\
    381.283778870433    -83.8088025294219\\
    444.838418264214    -84.6257729946545\\
    518.986721517599    -85.3174114538771\\
    605.49450329087 -85.8992134115439\\
    706.421914694448    -86.3844165254975\\
    824.172505032377    -86.784185316675\\
    961.55046144788 -87.1077938877716\\
    1121.82738961222    -87.3627940245955\\
    1308.8202258144 -87.5551617243539\\
    1526.98213589972    -87.6894186328864\\
    1781.50856578183    -87.768726851234\\
    2078.46096908265    -87.7949566190093\\
    2424.91115842832    -87.768726851234\\
    2829.10971807447    -87.6894186328864\\
    3300.68248854567    -87.5551617243539\\
    3850.85980249894    -87.3627940245955\\
    4492.74393097897    -87.1077938877716\\
    5241.62110920007    -86.784185316675\\
    6115.32557263395    -86.3844165254975\\
    7134.66427278985    -85.8992134115439\\
    8323.91238713707    -85.3174114538771\\
    9711.39142355757    -84.6257729946545\\
    11330.1436866739    -83.8088025294219\\
    13218.7191682208    -82.8485816267825\\
    15422.0936009669    -81.7246588621775\\
    17992.7395393026    -80.4140504017032\\
    20991.8759738877    -78.8914351984178\\
    24490.9262394715    -77.1296655616337\\
    28573.2189354276    -75.1007560490389\\
    33335.9723658003    -72.7775505278354\\
    38892.6097575773    -70.1362745521386\\
    45375.4603932603    -67.1601143625849\\
    52938.9109842187    -63.8437644168725\\
    61763.082333624 -60.1985005680472\\
    72058.1188473482    -56.2567865361712\\
    84069.1930459535    -52.074890263124\\
    98082.3442583926    -47.7318514170612\\
    114431.290543771    -43.3238058482039\\
    133505.376064586    -38.9541749354155\\
    155758.843175232    -34.721934720561\\
    181721.650037147    -30.7110619074575\\
    212012.091378157    -26.9837068111988\\
    247351.52295476 -23.578046695301\\
    288581.540375024    -20.5101344187963\\
    336684.021389482    -17.7781633316975\\
    392804.50894982 -15.3675363667826\\
    458279.491894321    -13.2556008465206\\
    534668.232939626    -11.4154805766546\\
    623789.901950712    -9.81886941436745\\
    727766.898804363    -8.43789270013325\\
    849075.397564178    -7.24623607584125\\
    990604.315658172    -6.21974724324063\\
    1155724.11238829    -5.33668371384572\\
    1348367.05518312    -4.57773726880744\\
    1573120.8651052 -3.92592715171453\\
    1835337.97174631    -3.36642346719528\\
    2141262.97937609    -2.88634004788449\\
    2498181.37990354    -2.47452075345443\\
    2914593.05419609    -2.1213330364438\\
    3400414.69362647    -1.818476119719\\
    3967215.96244253    -1.55880710027687\\
    4628495.02507993    -1.33618587793538\\
    5400000 -1.14533842499353\\
    54000000    -0.11454896491963\\
    5400000000.00001    -0.00114549117692524\\
    5400000000000.01    -1.1454911828029e-06\\
    5.40000000000001e+16    -1.1455085740759e-10\\
    1e+20   -6.36110936292703e-14\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Compensador}

    \addplot [color=mycolor2, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   -180\\
    8e-16   -180\\
    8e-11   -180.000000000115\\
    8e-07   -180.000001145774\\
    0.0008  -180.001145774465\\
    0.08    -180.114577293714\\
    0.8 -181.145621712936\\
    0.933658053253552   -181.336959148772\\
    1.08964670050651    -181.560225797393\\
    1.27169677141134    -181.820733759254\\
    1.48416241490592    -182.124669464953\\
    1.73212523876644    -182.47923201605\\
    2.02151584802252    -182.892790116095\\
    2.35925568910738    -183.375058075665\\
    2.75342259227421    -183.937289961205\\
    3.21344397160885    -184.59248848475\\
    3.7503223034646 -185.355621104547\\
    4.37689827615767    -186.243829156885\\
    5.10815790475775    -187.2766054568\\
    5.96159095633482    -188.475900120086\\
    6.95760925823194    -189.86609159238\\
    8.12003489417465    -191.473728583418\\
    9.47666996455751    -193.32690906509\\
    11.059961538044 -195.454119482564\\
    12.9077776983366    -197.882324963347\\
    15.0643132470732    -200.634109494109\\
    17.5811467248301    -203.723764026205\\
    20.5184740313374    -207.152473586121\\
    23.94654814979  -210.90320185489\\
    27.9473594095942    -214.936453377608\\
    32.6165964749238    -219.188561950195\\
    38.0659349606675    -223.574085876175\\
    44.4257084133164    -227.992937620594\\
    51.8480255394837    -232.341188159377\\
    60.5104082377934    -236.522895505586\\
    70.6200374460949    -240.459828366487\\
    82.4187083532673    -244.096923439784\\
    96.1886134909797    -247.403065784529\\
    112.259092021433    -250.368268892391\\
    131.014506645928    -252.998949325136\\
    152.903436528765    -255.312813998683\\
    178.44940610653 -257.334327191698\\
    208.263406387095    -259.091173524602\\
    243.05850821416 -260.611755775197\\
    283.666917007431    -261.923575569975\\
    331.059876881994    -263.052285533945\\
    386.370900200003    -264.021212511414\\
    450.922878143197    -264.851190108961\\
    526.259720718332    -265.560581571328\\
    614.183282939544    -266.16541079879\\
    716.796460362763    -266.679547427568\\
    836.553484701668    -267.114911899373\\
    976.318622461292    -267.481680006717\\
    1139.434680503  -267.788475257567\\
    1329.80295701001    -268.042543003412\\
    1551.97655006598    -268.249903703127\\
    1811.26925553721    -268.41548471773\\
    2113.8826588036 -268.543231172494\\
    2467.05446003127    -268.636197037316\\
    2879.2315805291 -268.696617906846\\
    3360.27219042869    -268.725967187325\\
    3612.10258138367    -268.729268172564\\
    3921.68148964712    -268.724997669322\\
    4576.88688138052    -268.693770945569\\
    5341.55911953932    -268.631678030243\\
    6233.9871111098 -268.537456158109\\
    7275.51533770813    -268.409209557302\\
    8491.05435827617    -268.244446691278\\
    9909.67660277276    -268.040153973272\\
    11565.3117066464    -267.79293717786\\
    13497.5580166224    -267.499276689392\\
    15752.6296768457    -267.155958009681\\
    18384.4619471348    -266.760743184957\\
    21456.0011895949    -266.313315619853\\
    25040.7103766038    -265.816414579141\\
    29224.3261278824    -265.276823638276\\
    34106.909300257 -264.705476961679\\
    39805.2381747168    -264.11552039015\\
    46455.601479375 -263.517073555915\\
    54217.0580499451    -262.908281342406\\
    63275.2410900582    -262.264475042261\\
    73846.798019116 -261.530285055769\\
    86184.5720969201    -260.620921201519\\
    100583.649755626    -259.435621782715\\
    117388.418274969    -257.879010506594\\
    137000.802601401    -255.880597139186\\
    159889.878313748    -253.404411539329\\
    186603.090651701    -250.44802307701\\
    217779.347936204    -247.036131174251\\
    254164.30254118 -243.214537952818\\
    296628.184896432    -239.047140852963\\
    346186.61706317 -234.615039282976\\
    404024.903687041    -230.015028066931\\
    471526.381302995    -225.355039844614\\
    550305.504031308    -220.745908774193\\
    642246.456985732    -216.291025323273\\
    749548.220922861    -212.076759159769\\
    874777.165958129    -208.166244779612\\
    1020928.4322489 -204.597623132381\\
    1191497.56570589    -201.386173321163\\
    1390564.12206664    -198.528814446764\\
    1622889.23891621    -196.009378555777\\
    1894029.50931581    -193.803511175315\\
    2210469.88059072    -191.882626561079\\
    2579778.75685993    -190.216783761374\\
    3010789.01494339    -188.776596730227\\
    3513809.26306152    -187.53438663354\\
    4100870.39506791    -186.464789975812\\
    4786013.33713027    -185.545002061582\\
    5585624.86898824    -184.754791184543\\
    6518829.55173024    -184.076378703206\\
    7607947.1359502 -183.494248448469\\
    8879026.39025901    -182.994925886441\\
    10362468.1178951    -182.566751626456\\
    12093752.26232  -182.199663399563\\
    14114286.4922105    -181.884993941545\\
    16472396.5617252    -181.615288069963\\
    19224482.1328011    -181.384139768603\\
    22436365.7036484    -181.186048683011\\
    224363657.036484    -180.118620128464\\
    22436365703.6484    -180.001186202826\\
    22436365703648.4    -180.000001186203\\
    2.24363657036484e+17    -180.000000000119\\
    1e+20   -180\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Loop de Corrente em Malha Aberta}

    \addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1e-20   -180\\
    6.66666666666759e-13    -180\\
    6.66666666666759e-08    -180.000000000024\\
    0.000666666666666758    -180.000000236073\\
    0.666666666666759   -180.000236073285\\
    66.6666666666759    -180.023607329832\\
    666.666666666759    -180.236074602627\\
    778.890771786889    -180.275815056519\\
    910.006251562037    -180.322245600732\\
    1063.19320741493    -180.37649261924\\
    1242.16706682281    -180.439872226768\\
    1451.26869804862    -180.51392227932\\
    1695.56969443962    -180.600439817031\\
    1980.99538188053    -180.701524880984\\
    2314.46853284847    -180.819631821607\\
    2704.07727273984    -180.957629433749\\
    3159.27125090315    -181.118871528005\\
    3691.09083434961    -181.307279904456\\
    4312.43488305253    -181.527442174756\\
    5038.37360151153    -181.784727551035\\
    5886.51405454719    -182.085424702835\\
    6877.42721261999    -182.436907269356\\
    8035.14688431749    -182.847834899514\\
    9387.75263721931    -183.328401157076\\
    10968.0508454207    -183.890644537805\\
    12814.3703819796    -184.548844625944\\
    14971.4922551726    -185.320028717059\\
    17491.7357361468    -186.224604810448\\
    20436.2273211267    -187.2870910375\\
    23876.3833058438    -188.536786577541\\
    27895.6419308485    -190.007970041347\\
    32591.4871095095    -191.738791934143\\
    38077.8128226072    -193.767543175115\\
    44487.6855260296    -196.124774365116\\
    51976.5715715652    -198.82045371378\\
    60726.1079193109    -201.827654993868\\
    70948.5075973192    -205.067961359596\\
    82891.7067593944    -208.406637637922\\
    96845.3781788223    -211.663945195676\\
    113147.957030528    -214.64144094858\\
    132194.849366409    -217.153559026002\\
    154448.022373859    -219.052658399743\\
    180447.209021576    -220.241484688588\\
    210822.998852379    -220.6746592913\\
    213109.73159745 -220.67647604311\\
    246312.1324298  -220.354473653799\\
    287775.370393042    -219.325292845045\\
    336218.370519995    -217.667968439156\\
    392816.079154819    -215.493338860231\\
    458941.228594731    -212.933273943705\\
    536197.631617386    -210.128781624384\\
    626459.080681065    -207.216574999007\\
    731914.795266769    -204.316870359465\\
    855122.519651245    -201.525088325046\\
    999070.558955123    -198.908689177517\\
    1167250.25810101    -196.508608826688\\
    1363740.68160092    -194.343654152818\\
    1593307.54801376    -192.416051143381\\
    1861518.81864921    -190.71680080173\\
    2174879.74402996    -189.230127046027\\
    2540990.6435564 -187.936805027144\\
    2968731.24519395    -186.816453457497\\
    3468476.05619497    -185.848996634766\\
    4052345.9885005 -185.015519118569\\
    4734502.34179533    -184.29870494777\\
    5531490.27454094    -183.683008247665\\
    6462640.0936024 -183.154659649791\\
    7550536.09542924    -182.701578997313\\
    8821564.33015925    -182.31323994062\\
    10306552.5742267    -181.980514806072\\
    12041518.0335007    -181.695516659275\\
    14068540.9118968    -181.451448091193\\
    16436785.0331718    -181.242461618085\\
    19203690.2702709    -181.063533760579\\
    22436365.7036484    -180.910353205177\\
    224363657.036484    -180.091050369797\\
    22436365703.6484    -180.000910505218\\
    22436365703648.4    -180.000000910505\\
    2.24363657036484e+17    -180.000000000091\\
    1e+20   -180\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Função de Transferência do Sistema Original}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.521in,
    height=3.566in,
    at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xtick={\empty},
    xlabel={Frequency  (rad/s)},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    title style={font=\bfseries},
    title={Bode Diagram},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=5.833in,
    height=4.375in,
    at={(0in,0in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: The problem is very easy to fix: either drop all the `forget plot`s or all `\addlegendentry` commands, or make sure that there are not more `\addlegendentry` than plots without `forget plot`.

Comment: It worked! Apparently this issue arrises with bodeplot matlab images. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!